# Angular displacment and "normal" displacment of a minutes hand in a clock/watch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, displacement

*Note : i'm using "normal" because i'm not really sure what is its correct name, i suppose linear is more correct.*

as a backstory, we were solving questions in today's class and this came up ( roughly translated ) :

> does each part of the minutes hand have the same angular displacment? Does it have the same "normal" displacment?

Now me and the teacher both agreed that the angular displacment should be equal and weren't sure about the other one, but it says in the solutions manual that :

> the "normal" displacment isn't equal, because $d$ is a function of $r$.

we use the relation $d=r\theta$ ( i suppose it should be $\Delta\theta$ but i will stick with curriculum, also r is the radius )

here was my argument :
if for the sake of contradiction we indeed had the "normal" displacment $d$, isn't equal then we should be able to find $d_1$ and $d_2$ such that for $d_1\not=d_2$ :

$$d_1=r\theta \implies \theta=\frac{d_1}{r}$$

similarily :

$$d_2=r\theta \implies \theta=\frac{d_2}{r}$$

now since the angular displacment is the same :

$$ \frac{d_1}{r} = \frac{d_2}{r} \implies d_1 = d_2 $$
which is a contradiction.

Now this would be evidently correct ( i think ) if the clock/watch was a circle, since r is fixed ( wasn't mentioned in the question ).

am i missing something?, everywhere i looked said that the " normal " displacment isn't the same, but i don't find it logical

Comment: [An ineffective explanation from the popular-physics literature](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1990/06/05).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is arc length the term you are looking for?

The angular displacement of each part of the minute hand is the same. But each travels a different arc length. This is because r is not the same for all parts of the minute hand.

If the point at the end of the minute hand is at distance $r$ from the center, the point in the middle is at $r/2$.

Comment: yes it was the arc length, by the way, why is r not the same for all parts of the minute hand?

Comment: @NormalHighstudent, each point on the minute hand is a different distance from the point of rotation.  The distance of a given point from the point of rotation is $r$ for that particular point.

Comment: thank you all, now i've got it, i was thinking that we were only consedering the tip of the minute hand ( aka points on circumference ), really appreciate it